# Nested loop pattern return null

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to make id for items. But after A6 B6.., it set to null.

The minimum number of item is 0 and max is 36. The pattern should be

A1-A6
B1-B6 
C1-C6
D1-D6
E1-E6 
F1-F6

For example if I have 32 items. The id should stop at F2.

My code:

```
    public void printMenu() {

        System.out.println("\nMenu:");
        System.out.printf("%s%9s%14s%8s\n", "Item#", "Item", "Price", "Qty");

        char letter = 'A';
        for (int i = 0; i < stock.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
                stock[i].setId(letter + "" + j);
                i++;
            }
            letter++;
        }

  for (int i = 0; i < stock.length; ++i) {
        System.out.printf("%s%15s%13s%8s\n" , stock[i].getId() ,stock[i].getDescription(),
                (stock[i].getPrice()),stock[i].getQuantity());
        }
    }
```

The output:

```
Menu:
    Item#     Item         Price     Qty
    A1        Gummies         -1.0      -1
    A2          Chips         -1.0      -1
    A3        Raisins         -1.0      -1
    A4       Pretzels         -1.0      -1
    A5         Cookie         -1.0      -1
    A6        Peanuts         -1.0      -1
    null        Gummies         -1.0      -1
    B1        Gummies         -1.0      -1
    B2          Chips         -1.0      -1
    B3        Raisins         -1.0      -1
    B4       Pretzels         -1.0      -1
    B5         Cookie         -1.0      -1
    B6        Peanuts         -1.0      -1
    null        Gummies         -1.0      -1
    C1        Gummies         -1.0      -1
    C2          Chips         -1.0      -1
    C3        Raisins         -1.0      -1
    C4       Pretzels         -1.0      -1
    C5         Cookie         -1.0      -1
    C6        Peanuts         -1.0      -1
    null        Gummies         -1.0      -1
    D1        Gummies         -1.0      -1
    D2          Chips         -1.0      -1
    D3        Raisins         -1.0      -1
    D4       Pretzels         -1.0      -1
    D5         Cookie         -1.0      -1
    D6        Peanuts         -1.0      -1
    null        Gummies         -1.0      -1
    E1        Gummies         -1.0      -1
    E2          Chips         -1.0      -1
    E3        Raisins         -1.0      -1
    E4       Pretzels         -1.0      -1
    E5         Cookie         -1.0      -1
    E6        Gummies         -1.0      -1
```

Comment: where you specify that you have 32 items in code?

Comment: The files may have up to 36 item that the final F6.

Comment: Can you also provide the Stock class for some tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit - Explanation with Example** : 
 
A detailed Explanation. 
The output of this loop, if you see closely, the value of i is skipped from 5-7, so array at position 6 was untouched. Resulting in the `id` property not getting set. **Look at line `5 A6 - 7 B1` after A6, index of 7 was updated and not 6.**

```
 int stock[] = new int[40];
 char letter = 'A';

 // After j loop exists, here i again gets incremented.
 for (int i = 0; i < stock.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
        System.out.println(i + " " + letter + j);
        i++; // This increments the value of i
    }
    letter++;
 }

0 A1
1 A2
2 A3
3 A4
4 A5
5 A6
7 B1
8 B2
9 B3
10 B4
11 B5
12 B6
14 C1
15 C2
16 C3
17 C4
18 C5
19 C6
21 D1
22 D2
23 D3
24 D4
25 D5
26 D6
28 E1
29 E2
30 E3
31 E4
32 E5
33 E6
35 F1
36 F2
37 F3
38 F4
39 F5
40 F6
```

**Original Answer :**

The value of `i` in the nested loop, is incremented twice skipping one value entirely whenever `j` loop ends.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < stock.length; ++i) { // After j loop exists, here i again gets incremented.
        for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
            stock[i].setId(letter + "" + j);
            i++; // This increments the value of i 
        }
        letter++;
    }
```

You can remove the incrementing of i in `i` loop.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < stock.length; ) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
            stock[i].setId(letter + "" + j);
            i++; // This increments the value of i 
        }
        letter++;
    }
```

or use a while outside

```
int i = 0;
while(i < stock.length) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
            stock[i].setId(letter + "" + j);
            i++; // This increments the value of i 
        }
        letter++;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that the loop is the problem.  If you only print out the value, you'll see A1-F6 printed correctly.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for down votes. If you closely analyze the loops, after initializing an entire character it always skips one place in the actual array. This is the reason for null in the output.

Comment: I Agree with @BandiKishore. The issue is with the loop, why the downvotes. Is something wrong with the explanation?

Comment: The explanation was less clear.  I admit my error in only looking at the output.  This is correct.

Comment: @swis Welcome! Can you accept the answer and close out the question?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: @swis I guess you don't actually have that length.
Change your `for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++)` to `for (int j = 1; j < 7 && i < stock.length; j++)`